# What does "deceptive request routing" mean in the new HTTP spec (RFC 7231)?

Tags: http

In [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1), the 400 response code was for syntax errors.

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

[RFC 7231](https://httpwg.github.io/specs/rfc7231.html#status.4xx) broadens the applicability of 400. The spec gives a few other examples of client errors, but I'm not sure what they mean.

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

In particular, what would constitute "deceptive request routing"?

Comment: A possible scenario is an unknown name in the Host request header. This might happen if the client is using an incorrect IP address, either because of a DNS issue or a DNS rebinding attack. I am not aware of a more specific 4xx status code for that situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As one example, this could be relevant for a CDN. See [RFC 3568](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3568#section-4).

Section 4.1.2 stands out to me:

> This technique involves the task of using HTTP [4] such as Cookie, Language, and User-Agent, in order to select a surrogate.  In [20] some examples of using this technique are provided.

The relevancy of the cited example ("deceptive request routing") comes in when a system relies on information including custom HTTP headers for decision making. When such a header is absent, stale, incorrect, or otherwise not processable. As as general rule, anything malformed or "wrong" coming from the public Internet can safely be assumed malicious (or "deceptive").

---

Another example: someone Man-In-The-Middles my uplink and hijacks my session cookie. Tries to access the site with that cookie, but all of a sudden the system sees requests with the same token coming from two different IP addresses.

Comment: it could be related to some sort of blocking from the ISP?